# Why when trying to delete a file from my ftp server i'm getting exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp, treeview

This is how i select the file to be deleted from a treeView1:
I make right click on a file in the treeView in the menu options select "Delete"
Then calling the delete method.

```
private void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Delete")
            {
                delete(treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath);
            }
        }
```

This is the method to delete the file:

```
public void delete(string deleteFile)
        {
            try
            {               
                FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
                FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;
                string url = "ftp://" + txtHost.Text + "/" + deleteFile;
                url = url.Replace('\\', '/');
                Uri serverUri = new Uri(url);
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);// + "/" + deleteFile);
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }
```

The path of the file to delete since it's a treeView in the variable deleteFile look like this:

root\B\a-new-beginning.jpg

So i'm using the replace: url = url.Replace('\', '/');
In the end in serverUri i see: ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/root/B/a-new-beginning.jpg

This is the right format same for uploading a file.
But then i'm getting exception on this line:

```
ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Webexception:

The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at FTP_ProgressBar.Form1.delete(String deleteFile) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\Form1.cs:line 665
  InnerException:
```

Line 665 is:

```
ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Maybe something with the Replace is wrong ?

This is a screenshot of my ftp server file manager at ipage.com my host.

[image: MyFtpServer]

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at FTP_ProgressBar.Form1.delete(String deleteFile) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\Form1.cs:line 656
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Something wrong with credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change the setting to `ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;` currently it is set to `true`.

You can try to access the actual response message from the server using the `((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription` property to get an insight into the specific error.

```
try
{
        //Your code
}
catch(WebException e)
{
        String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
}
```

And also there could be issue with `ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;`. I thing this should not be set while deleting a file. Just a thought.

Let me know if that helps.

Updated Code:

```
private void Delete(string remoteFile) {
  string deleteRequest = ftpServer + remoteFile;
  FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(deleteRequest);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpLoginName, ftpLoginPassword);
  request.Proxy = null;
  request.UseBinary = false;
  request.UsePassive = true;
  request.KeepAlive = false;
  FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
  sr.ReadToEnd();
  string StatusCode = response.StatusDescription;
  sr.Close();
  response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Avijit the exception i'm getting is: 550 root/1.png: No such file or directory\r\n and i entered the path like this: reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/root/1.png"); and i'm sure this is the path.

Comment: Avijit i also edited my question added a screenshot of my ftp server file manager you can see the main directory is root then the file 1.png before i tried root/b/....but now for testing i tried only root/1.png but it's not working either.

Comment: @JorgeHyyest have you used ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false; ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;

Comment: I think there is a problem with the ipage.com servers i'm trying to contact the live chat support. I tried now other parts that was working on my program and every place give me exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive the problem is no on my side. At least i think. Maybe i have internet problems but i can surf no problems and even surf to my ftp file manager and log in and surf other websites so it seems to me that something is wrong with the ipage.com servers somewhere.

Comment: ok. I am posting another code. You may check it when ur server is up.

Comment: Your code is working but my code was suppose to work also. It was my silly stupid mistake. In the ftp path i add the root name and it's not suppose to be. I did: remoteFile = "/root/1.png"; so all the time the path was ftp.....newsxpressmedia.com/root/1.png but the root is the mistake. The correctp ath is: ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/1.png

Comment: Sorry for all the troubles.